# Finding average of data within a certain range

Tags: sql

How do I find the average of data set within a certain range? Specifically I am looking to find the average for a data set for all data points that are within one standard deviations of the original average. Here is an example:

```
Student_ID  Test_Scores
1           3
1           20
1           30
1           40
1           50
1           60
1           95
```

Average = 42.571

Standard Deviation = 29.854

I want to find all data points that are within one standard deviation of this original average, so within the range (42.571-29.854)<=Data<=(42.571+29.854). And from here I want to recalculate a new average.

So my desired data set is:

```
Student_ID  Test_Scores
1           20
1           30
1           40
1           50
1           60
```

My desired new average is: 40

Here is my following SQL code and it didn't yield my desired result:

```
SELECT
    Student_ID,
    AVG(Test_Scores)
FROM
    Student_Data
WHERE
    Test_Scores BETWEEN (AVG(Test_Scores)-STDEV(Test_Scores)) AND (AVG(Test_Scores)+STDEV(Test_Scores))
ORDER BY
    Student_ID
```

Anyone know how I could fix this?

Comment: please tag the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use either window functions or do the calculation in a subquery:

```
SELECT sd.Student_ID, sd.Test_Scores
FROM Student_Data sd CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT AVG(Test_Scores) as avgts, STDEV(Test_Scores) as stdts
      FROM Student_Data
     ) x
WHERE sd.Test_Scores BETWEEN avgts - stdts AND avgts + stdts
ORDER BY sd.Student_ID;
```

Comment: This query yielded my desired data set! But what if I want to take the average of this new data set? I tried doing: AVG(sd.Test_Scores) at the first SELECT Statement but this didn't change anything

Comment: @TwistedCandle . . . You would make this a subquery and do:  `select avg(test_scores) from (<query here>) q`.

Comment: .....So I would have to do: select avg(test_scores) from (SELECT sd.Student_ID, sd.Test_Scores
FROM Student_Data sd CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT AVG(Test_Scores) as avgts, STDEV(Test_Scores) as stdts
      FROM Student_Data
     ) x
WHERE sd.Test_Scores BETWEEN avgts - stdts AND avgts + stdts
ORDER BY sd.Student_ID)

Comment: Sorry if it is confusing but I simply copied the entire query you wrote and put it inside the (<query here>) part. Or is that wrong?

Comment: @TwistedCandle . . . leave out the `order by` and remember the table alias.

Comment: So I would have to do: select avg(sd.test_scores)? Sorry for so many questions I am new to SQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
select avg(
            select test_scores from table where 
                test_scores between
                                   (
                                    (select avg(test_scores) from table)-(select stddev(test_scores) from table)) 
                                    and 
                                    (
                                    (select avg(test_scores) from table)+(select stddev(test_scores) from table))
           );
```